# How to split a string and add new line before date

Tags: perl

How to split a string and add new line before date?

For Ex,

```
$string = 4/25/2011 11:34:07 AM [test] >> Need to change.  5/16/2011 10:44:45 AM [test] >> Nothing to change yet. Need to review information.  5/23/2011 11:13:39 AM [test] >> Working on it.
```

Expected result:

```
4/25/2011 11:34:07 AM [test] >> Need to change.  
5/16/2011 10:44:45 AM [test] >> Nothing to change yet. Need to review information.  
5/23/2011 11:13:39 AM [test] >> Working on it.
```

I tried with

```
my @words1 = split /\d{2}\\\d{2}\\(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s+\d{2}:\d{2}/, $str;
```

But did not return with desired output

Comment: By writing code.

Comment: Tried with split with dot for now but im trying regex as well @words1 = split /\./, $str;

Comment: Edit your question to add the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very good form to bring just a requirement to Stack Overflow without obviously having tried to solve the problem yourself. Without any code there is nothing to "help" with, and I hope you'll at least make an effort in the future

Assuming there is always some whitespace before each date, this will work for you

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $string = '4/25/2011 11:34:07 AM [test] >> Need to change.  5/16/2011 10:44:45 AM [test] >> Nothing to change yet. Need to review information.  5/23/2011 11:13:39 AM [test] >> Working on it.';

$string =~ s|\s+(?=\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4})|\n|g;

say $string;
```

#### output

```
4/25/2011 11:34:07 AM [test] >> Need to change.
5/16/2011 10:44:45 AM [test] >> Nothing to change yet. Need to review information.
5/23/2011 11:13:39 AM [test] >> Working on it.
```

Comment: I tried my @words1 = split /\d{2}\\\d{2}\\(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\s+\d{2}:\d{2}/, $str; but it did not return with desired output.

Comment: @VimalRaj: That's not what I wrote

Comment: Thanks for your help @Borodin. I have mentioned what I have tried earlier. Your code piece worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
my $string = "4/25/2011 11:34:07 AM [test] >> Need to change.  5/16/2011 10:44:45 AM [test] >> Nothing to change yet. Need to review information.  5/23/2011 11:13:39 AM [test] >> Working on it.";

$string=~s/\b(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})/\n$1/igs;

$string=~s/^\s*//igs;

print"$string\n";`
```

Comment: No need to use `is` flag for this situation.